# Unable to make API requests in AWS EC2 Windows instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have made a spring boot REST API (as a jar file) which links to MongoDB compass installed on the same EC2 instance.

When I run the jar file (in cmd) on my Windows 10 laptop (not the EC2 instance), it works totally fine and I'm able to make the http requests with Postman (from my IP). And when I run the jar file on my EC2 instance with cmd, it still runs normal and everything seems fine.

But this time I'm unable to make the http requests from anywhere. Postman says `Could not send request Error: Request timed out`.

I've tried using both the public IP and Public DNS IP. Going through the other solutions to questions similar as mine, I got to know that I'd to add inbound rules for all the ports which I'm using (8080 and 27017 in my case). I also enabled stuff from Windows Firewall in the EC2 instance but nothing helps me at the end.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try to check in your Windows 10 VM instance if the port 8080 is actively running with tnc your_url_or_ip -port 80

Comment: you mean "telnet <url> <port>" ?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed I tried doing telnet localhost 8080 and the cmd screen goes blank. When I try telnet localhost 80 it says "Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed"

Comment: Hey,turning off the firewall entirely probably fixed it for me. But I guess it is not safe.